# Adding files sizes using bash command "wc"

Tags: bash, find

I ran this command to find each file modified yesterday:

```
find /eqtynas/ -type f -mtime -1 > /home/writtenToStorage.20171026 &
```

and then developed this script to add up all the files collected by the script, and sum the sizes. .

```
#!/bin/bash
ydate=$(date +%Y%m%d --date="yesterday")
file="/home/writtenToStorage.$ydate"
fileSize=0
for line in $(cat $file)
    do
    if [ -f $line ] && [ -s $line ] ; then
    fileSize1=$fileSize
    fileSize=$(wc -c < $line)
    Total=$(( $fileSize + $fileSize1 ))
fi
done

echo $Total
```

However when I stat just one of the files in the list It comes out to 18942, where as the total for all the files combined comes out at 34499.

```
wc -c /eqty/fixed
18942 /eqty/fixed
```

Is the script ok - because I ran another check and the total size was 314 gigs

find /eqtynas/ -type f -mtime -1 -print0 | du -ch  --files0-from=- --total -s > 24hourUsage.20171026 &

Comment: Well, `-mtime -1` doesn't run from `00:00` it is the number of 24 blocks ago the file was modified with the fractional parts ignored. This can effect your calculations. `$(cat $file)` is a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use of `cat`*). Why not `while read -r line; do .... done <"$file"` Use `stat -c %s "$file"` for the file size.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment, you may prefer something similar to:

```
sum=
while read -r sz; do 
    sum=$((sum + sz)) 
done < <(find /eqtynas/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec stat -c %s '{}' \; )
echo "sum: $sum"
```

There are a number of ways to do this. You can also pipe the result of `-exec ls -al '{}'` to `awk` and just sum the 5th field.

If you have already written the filenames to `/home/writtenToStorage.20171026`, then you can simply redirect the file to your `while` loop, e.g.

```
while read -r sz; do
    sum=$((sum + sz))
done <"/home/writtenToStorage.20171026"
```

Look things over and let me know i you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding to `Total`, you're just setting it to the sum of the sizes of the last two files.

```
for line in $(cat $file)
    do
    if [ -f $line ] && [ -s $line ] ; then
        fileSize=$(wc -c < $line)
        ((Total += fileSize))
    fi
done
```